# How to fix specflow file generation?

Tags: c#, specflow, visual-studio-2019

When I'm trying to edit something in my feature files, my feature file disappears and I'm getting couple of errors.

[image]

Looks like my feature.cs files cannot be generated from feature files.

Comment: Did you check what the error messages are saying?

Comment: @AndreasWillich, But my teammates have the same configuration with specflowSingleFileGenerator and everything works perfectly..

Comment: Then they have probably not the latest VS Extension. We rolled a new one out on Tuesday which adds this error messages.

Comment: @AndreasWillich,so what will you suggest me?

Comment: @AndreasWillich, should I rollback the extension version? If yes, how can i do this? Please,help?

Comment: Open an issue on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow

Comment: @AndreasWillich,Have already done this.Here is the link : https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1557

Comment: Ah, I didn't saw this yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring due to the updates coming from specflow extension. On May 9th , a recent update was made from specflow, which screwed up most of the feature files. 
So go to extensions and updates , search for specflow and uncheck the automatically update this extension checkbox. And roll back the previous version. Yous should be good